# Debugging the loading & activation of Silverlight components

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, remote-debugging

Is there anyway to get detailed debugging information when a Silverlight component is loaded into a web page via an XAP file?

I'm not talking about adding debug statements in the Silverlight component but from the host environment (web browser).

Cheers

AWC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the question. What sort of debug information is it you want?

It is possible to use windbg with silverlight, see the link below. I have only used it myself when trying to pinpoint memory leaks, but I am sure there are tons of possibilities that I don't know about.

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2008/08/25/debugging-silverlight-applications-sos-dll.aspx